# How to get number of sheet from list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What script should do. First, get sheet names from range on sheet List_1. Then, using this array of names, put some data only on these sheets.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xdws6Vr6YVXuj19mvpOvkpJokOfY2T7Sh1aMpous_Xw/edit#gid=0

```
function VList() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheetNames = ss.getSheetByName("List_1");
var rangeNames = sheetNames.getRange("B3:B5").getValues();

  for (var sheetId = 0; sheetId<sheets.length; sheetId++){
   if(sheets[sheetId].getSheetName() == rangeNames) {
   ss.getRange("C1").setValue("done");  
    }
   } 
}
```

Problem. When script starts - nothing happens. How to get number of sheet and vlookup only on them? Maybe, exist some function like "getSheetId" which can get number of sheet.

Solved, thanks to bruce.

```
function VList() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheetNames = ss.getSheetByName("List_1").getRange("B3:B5").getValues();

 sheetNames.forEach(function(row) {
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName (row[0]);
 if (!sheet) throw 'missing sheet ' + row[0];
 sheet.getRange("c1").setValue ("done");
 });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getValues() returns a two dimensional array, which you then compare with a string value - so that will never be true.

Once you fix that,  you will still be updating the same cell, C1 with 'done' multiple times - ss points to the List_1 sheet - I assume you mean to update the sheet whose name is in the list.

Why not just use the list in b3:b5 to simply get each sheet by name and update it? There's no need to go through the sheets list since you already know their names.

something like

```
ss.getSheetByName("List_1").getRange("b3:b5").getValues()
.forEach(function(row) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName (row[0]);
  if (!sheet) throw 'missing sheet ' + row[0];
  sheet.getRange("c1").setValue ("done");
});
```

Comment: Thanks bruce, now it works! Never use forEach, so its new experience for me)